# Shopify Theme section is ignoring the stylesheet and the javascript can't access global objects

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I'm making a custom section for Shopify theme using Liquid and the code for /sections/mytest.liquid is below.

I expect to see the section with red border, and I expect to see the section ID in the browser console.

It doesn't work because shopify is ignoring my stylesheet.   And it always says section ID is missing.  what am I doing wrong?

```
<div id="fish1">
Hello this is the threshold -- {{ section.settings.threshold }} --
</div>

{% javascript %}
console.log('THE SECTION ID IS ' + (section ? section.id : 'MISSING'));
{% endjavascript %}

{% stylesheet %}
#fish1 {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: cyan;
}
{% endstylesheet %}

{% schema %}
{
  "name": "test Header",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "range",
      "id": "threshold",
      "min": 300, "max": 1000, "step": 10, "unit": "px",
      "label": "Threshold",
      "default": 760
    }
  ],
  "presets": [
    {
      "category": "My Stuff",
      "name": "My Test"
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember that Liquid is a templating language that is compiled server-side to create a document that will be served to the client's browser, and that Javascript is a client-side script that will be parsed once the page is served.  From the Javascript side, the client won't know any of the variables you set through the theme or section settings unless you drop them into your template somehow.

Here's some code that might help you get started (I generally use basic `<script>` tags rather than Shopify's `{% javascript %}` liquid tags, but this *should* work inside those as well):

```
<script>
  const section = {
    settings: {{ section.settings | json }},
    id: {{ section.id | json }}
  }

  console.log('Confirmation:', section.id, section.settings);
</script>
```

Note the use of the `| json` filter - this filter will guarantee that whatever variable you have before the filter will be output to the resulting document in a Javascript-friendly way, and it works for non-objects as well.  Strings will be wrapped in quotes, quotes within the string will be escaped, empty values will be `null`, etc.  My rule-of-thumb is that any time you are dropping Liquid variables into Javascript, the `json` filter should be used.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The mustache things don't work in {% javascript %}.  Apparently this is a bug in shopify.  Curiously none of the shopify sections use {% javascript %} or {% stylesheet %}.  It makes me sad, because using {% .. %} is so much better because in theory they would be transpiled and aggregated on the server. But it seems to be broken, and nobody (not even shopify builtin themes) uses them.  So I'm not going to keep trying.  I'll just use the <script> and <style> like everyone else.

Comment: Huh. Makes me not feel too bad for still making my scripts the old way! 
One of the patterns I often use though is to put almost-all of the code for whatever feature into an asset file, then use the inline-script in the section for the sole purpose of initializing the class with the relevant section/block settings.  (BTW, If you ever need to pass block-settings in, you can use `{{ section.block | map: 'settings' | json }}` to get a block-setting array)

Answer (score 1):

There is no global `section` javascript variable in a section file, that's why you get the error that there is no `id` of undefined.

You can do this:

```
{% javascript %}
console.log('THE SECTION ID IS {{section.id}}');
{% endjavascript %}
```

As for the stylesheet there is no problem for me. I tested it and it applies a border to the div.

Comment: Thank you!  This is really strange.  The styles are working for me now also. I am using "theme watch" to upload, and dynamic sections (using the online store/customize) and the styles do not work at first. But then I try again in 10 minutes and it works!  That's so weird. Is there some server-side cache? Can I turn it off?

Comment: The Javascript is still not working.  I look at the generated code in the debugger (in scripts.js) and it has `  try {    
console.log('THE SECTION ID IS {{section.id}}');
  } catch(e) { console.error(e); }`  as you can see, the mustache is not expanded

Answer (score 0):

Also it seems like the stylesheet parser is very sensitive for commenting inline in CSS using // or /* */. I had to remove all of those, and also replace all single quotes ' with double ".